# SQL: Repeat a result row multiple times, and number the rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

I have a SQL query with a result like this:

```
value | count
------+------
foo   |     1
bar   |     3
baz   |     2
```

Now I want to expand this so that each row with a `count` larger than 1 occurs multiple times. I also need these rows to be numbered. So I would get:

```
value | count | index
------+-------+------
foo   |     1 |     1
bar   |     3 |     1
bar   |     3 |     2
bar   |     3 |     3
baz   |     2 |     1
baz   |     2 |     2
```

I have to make this work on all the major databases (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and maybe more). So a solution that works across different databases would be ideal, but clever ways to make it work on any database are appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For MySQL, use the poor man's [generate_series](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20generate_series), which is done via views. MySQL is the only RDBMS among [big four](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10424245) that don't has any CTE feature.

Actually you can use this technique on database that supports view. So that's virtually all database

Generator technique sourced here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator#mysql_generator_code

The only minor modification we made is we replace the bitwise (**shift left** and **bitwise or**) technique from the original technique with mere multiplication and addition respectively; as Sql Server and Oracle has no shift left operator.

This abstraction is 99% guaranteed to work on all database, except Oracle; Oracle's `SELECT` can't function without any table, in order to do this, one need to select from dummy table, Oracle provided one already, it's called `DUAL` table. Database portability is a pipe dream :-)

Here's the abstracted views that works on all RDBMS, devoid of bitwise operations(which is not really a necessity anyway in this scenario) and feature nuances(we remove `OR REPLACE` on `CREATE VIEW`, only Postgresql and MySQL supports them) among all major database.

Oracle caveat: Just put `FROM DUAL` after each `SELECT` expression

```
CREATE VIEW generator_16
AS SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3   UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL
   SELECT 6   UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL
   SELECT 9   UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL
   SELECT 12  UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 15;

CREATE VIEW generator_256
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n * 16 ) + lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_16 lo, generator_16 hi;

CREATE VIEW generator_4k
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n * 256 ) + lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_256 lo, generator_16 hi;

CREATE VIEW generator_64k
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n * 256 ) + lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_256 lo, generator_256 hi;

CREATE VIEW generator_1m
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n * 65536 ) + lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_64k lo, generator_16 hi;
```

Then use this query:

```
SELECT t.value, t.cnt, i.n
FROM tbl t
JOIN generator_64k i 
ON i.n between 1 and t.cnt
order by t.value, i.n
```

Postgresql: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1541d/1

Oracle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/26c05/1

Sql Server: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84bee/1

MySQL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78f5b/1

Comment: I like this answer best because it's portable.

Comment: This answer helped me solve a major issue in our queries and helped me in constructing an entire new range of reports using this code. Wish I could do more than just up voting this answer. :)

Answer (score 33):

You could use a numbers table

```
SELECT value, count, number
FROM table
    JOIN Numbers 
        ON table.count >= Numbers.number
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle using MSSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fcf3d/3)

Comment: Any insight into why this works? Worked great for my solution 4 years later btw.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that instead of joining on 1 row, it joins on all the rows up until the number after the count. ie. Count = 3, then it matches 1,2,3 creating a 3|1, 3|2, and 3|3 result

Comment: what is numbrs table?? is it system table?

Answer (score 8):

You asked for a db-agnostic solution and @Justin gave you a nice one.
You also asked for

> clever ways to make it work on any database

There is one for **PostgreSQL: [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html)** does what you asked for out of the box:

```
SELECT val, ct, generate_series(1, ct) AS index
FROM   tbl;
```

BTW, I'd rather not use `value` and `count` as column names. It's bad practice to use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifiers. Using `val` and `ct` instead.

Comment: Brilliant! I wish this worked everywhere. And yeah you're right about the reserved words, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 7):

MySQL is really the IE of the database world, it's such a holdout when it comes to standards and features.

Works on all major RDBMS except MySQL:

```
with 
-- Please add this on Postgresql:
-- RECURSIVE
tbl_populate(value, cnt, ndx) as
(
  select value, cnt, 1 from tbl

  union all

  select t.value, t.cnt, tp.ndx + 1
  from tbl t
  join tbl_populate tp 
  on tp.value = t.value  
  and tp.ndx + 1 <= t.cnt
)
select * from tbl_populate
order by cnt, ndx
```

SQL Server : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/911a9/1

Oracle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/198cd/1

Postgresql: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/0b03d/1

Comment: Nice, it works, although I don't quite understand what it's doing :-)

Comment: Heheh really? Now I'm inspired to do a blog about recursion on CTE. But basically, row generators are the easiest kind of CTE recursion to make, it follows the logic of tail recursion; tail recursion almost have one-to-one correspondence with loop. Hierarchical recursions and object graph recursions on CTE are the ones a bit harder to understand

Comment: shouldn't there be a `recursive` keyword after the `with` ?

Comment: @vyegorov true, for Postgresql only :-) In fact that keyword is included on my sqlfiddle, check the last link(Postgresql) of this answer. Other databases can infer recursion and has no need for that `recursive` directive. database portability is really a pipe dream :-)

Answer (score 4):

Create a numbers table - its definition may vary slightly depending on platform (this is for SQL Server):

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers(Number INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT Numbers 
SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
FROM sys.all_columns;
```

Now this temp is also SQL Server, but demonstrates the join syntax that should be valid across the RDBMSes you specify (though I will confess I don't use them so I can't test):

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE(value VARCHAR(32), [count] INT);

INSERT @foo SELECT 'foo', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'bar', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 'baz', 2;

SELECT f.value, f.[count], [index] = n.Number
FROM @foo AS f, Numbers AS n
WHERE n.Number <= f.[count];
```

Results (again, SQL Server):

```
value | count | index
------+-------+------
foo   |     1 |     1
bar   |     3 |     1
bar   |     3 |     2
bar   |     3 |     3
baz   |     2 |     1
baz   |     2 |     2
```

Answer (score 2):

For appreciation only, SQL Server 2005 and later can handle this recursively:

```
declare @Stuff as Table ( Name VarChar(10), Number Int )
insert into @Stuff ( Name, Number ) values ( 'foo', 1 ), ( 'bar', 3 ), ( 'baz', 2 )

select * from @Stuff

; with Repeat ( Name, Number, Counter ) as (
  select Name, Number, 1
    from @Stuff
    where Number > 0
  union all
  select Name, Number, Counter + 1
    from Repeat
    where Counter < Number
  )
select *
  from Repeat
  order by Name, Counter -- Group by name.
  option ( maxrecursion 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

By a simple `JOIN` you can reach to the aim of repeating records n times.

The following query repeats each record 20 times.

```
SELECT  TableName.*
FROM    TableName
JOIN    master.dbo.spt_values on type = 'P' and number < 20
```

**Note for `master.dbo.spt_values on type = 'P'`:**

This table is used for getting a series of number which is hard-coded in it by condition of `type='P'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use of CTE :

```
WITH Numbers(Num) AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Num
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Num + 1
    FROM   Numbers c
    WHERE  c.Num < 1000
)

SELECT VALUE,COUNT, number
FROM   TABLE
       JOIN Numbers
            ON  TABLE.count >= Numbers.Num
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, we could use a combination of `LEVEL` and `CROSS JOIN`.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM yourtable
         CROSS JOIN (    SELECT ROWNUM index_t
                           FROM DUAL
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX (count_t) FROM yourtable))
   WHERE index_t <= count_t
ORDER BY VALUE, index_t;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/148f9e/14)

Answer (score 0):

WITH Numbers(Num) AS
(
SELECT 1 AS Num
UNION ALL
SELECT Num + 1
FROM   Numbers c
WHERE  c.Num < 1000
)

SELECT VALUE,COUNT, number
FROM   TABLE
JOIN Numbers
ON  TABLE.count >= Numbers.Num
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).