# Adding rows to an output

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY a.jpnum, a.jptask 
                      ORDER BY a.jpnum, a.jptask) rn,  
  a.jpnum, 
  a.jptask, 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR (a.description, '[^,]+', 1, 3) col_3,  
  REGEXP_REPLACE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (a.description, 
                                 '[^,]+', 1, 3),  'C-.*' ) mytest  
FROM My.task a 
WHERE a.jpnum = '13788';
```

The output is:

```
RN  JPNUM  JPTASK  COL_3      MYTEST
1     13788  10            7C-4E SIG    7
1     13788  20            9C-6E SIG    9
```

So far so good... But here is what I'm stuck on. I need each row repeated as many times as the number in MY TEST. So... taking the first 2 for an example. I need to get:

```
RN  JPNUM   JPTASK  COL_3   MYTEST
---------------------------------------
1   13788   10   7C-4E SIG   7 
2   13788   10   7C-4E SIG   7 
3   13788   10   7C-4E SIG   7 
4   13788   10   7C-4E SIG   7 
5   13788   10   7C-4E SIG   7 
6   13788   10   7C-4E SIG   7 
7   13788   10   7C-4E SIG   7 
1   13788   20   9C-6E SIG   9 
2   13788   20   9C-6E SIG   9 
3   13788   20   9C-6E SIG   9 
4   13788   20   9C-6E SIG   9 
5   13788   20   9C-6E SIG   9 
6   13788   20   9C-6E SIG   9 
7   13788   20   9C-6E SIG   9 
8   13788   20   9C-6E SIG   9 
9   13788   20   9C-6E SIG   9
```

I have hundreds of these to run, and MYTEST could go as high as 300

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems. It would be helpful to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Your right... I'm sorry.. Oracle SQL Woking with 10G (i beleive)

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach to this problem is:

1. Generate a table containing a number sequence at least as high as the maximum number of repeats you want.
2. Join to the sequence table where the number in the sequence table is <= the thing you want to repeate (in this case `MYTEST`).

The exact implementation depends on what database you are using, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423767/sql-repeat-a-result-row-multiple-times-and-number-the-rows) has all of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a list of numbers up to 300 to do a query.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY a.jpnum, a.jptask 
                           ORDER BY a.jpnum, a.jptask) rn,
       jpnum, jptask, col_3, mytest
from (select a.jpnum, a.jptask, 
             REGEXP_SUBSTR (a.description, '[^,]+', 1, 3) col_3,  
             REGEXP_REPLACE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (a.description, 
                             '[^,]+', 1, 3),  'C-.*' ) mytest  
      FROM My.task a 
      WHERE a.jpnum = '13788'
    ) t join
    (select row_number() over (order by column_name) as num
     from Information_Schema.Columns
    ) numbers
    on numbers.num <= cast(mytest as int)
```

You can put any table in the second subquery that has at least 300 rows.  Depending on the database, there are other ways to express this query, but the approach is often the same:  join to a table of numbers to get the additional rows.