# Select rows repeated for certain count

Tags: mysql, sql

SO,

I have an issue about query in MySQL DBMS. I have table `repeats` with data, like:

```
+--------+-----+
| record | num |
+--------+-----+
|  foo   |  2  |
+--------+-----+
|  bar   |  3  |
+--------+-----+
|  baz   |  1  |
+--------+-----+
```

here `record` field contains some data (irrelevant, let it be simple string) and `num` field contains number of repeats of current row in the result set. So, I want to result in:

```
foo
foo
bar
bar
bar
baz
```

i.e. `'foo'` was repeated twice, `'bar'` - three times and `'baz'` - once.

Ok, now what I've tried. I've created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `natural` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

-then filled it with natural numbers, from `1` till `MAX(num)` from `repeats` table. After this, I can achieve my goal via:

```
SELECT 
  `repeats`.record 
FROM 
  `natural` 
    LEFT JOIN `repeats` 
      ON `natural`.id<=`repeats`.num
WHERE 
  `repeats`.record IS NOT NULL
```

-this works well, but I don't want to use `natural` table. And so, my question is: is it possible to achieve my goal with repetition of rows in a single SQL-query, without creating temporary data-structure? (Since it is MySQL, tricks with variables will also fit - I just have no idea now of how to do that).  However, answer *'no, this is impossible because ..'* will also be welcome.

*I also suspect that it is some 'common' problem, but have not found any corresponding info, unfortunately.* Update: [here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423767/sql-repeat-a-result-row-multiple-times-and-number-the-rows) a similar problem (yet in the same time - not fully similar since it also upcomes to sequence generation problem which I want to avoid)

Comment: actually I think you can just create and leave this table with numbers in your db, it's the fastest way to create sequence of numbers as far as I know.

Comment: @RomanPekar but I've mentioned that. My question is - how to avoid that (and, ok - let it be not the 'fastest' way)

Comment: I think there's no way you can do it in MySQL if you dont't have a table with guaranteed amount of rows. If you have such a table, you can generate sequence by `select @rownum:=@rownum+1 n, t.* from tbl t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r` and then cross join it a number of times - looks very alike as creating view and cross join it to yourself several time.

Comment: @RomanPekar - nevermind now :\ Thanks. Somehow my question was marked as duplicated of irrelevant question (that one has no solution for my problem, important part of which is _"resolve without temporary structures"_). Ah, sometimes I'm stuck with SO  :\

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e579c/1

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo as an acacademic task it can be solved without temp structures - just inner join with subquery of union 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on :) but as practical it's better to go with table of number from 1 to some large number with primary key by this number

Comment: @Justin, wow, **looks interesting** - may be that I'm seeking for :)