# Select a row X times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very specific sql problem.

I have a table given with order positions (each position belongs to one order, but this isn't a problem):

```
|  Article ID  |  Amount  |
|--------------|----------|
|     5        |    3     |
|     12       |    4     |
```

For the customer, I need an export with every physical item that is ordered, e.g.

```
|  Article ID  |  Position  |
|--------------|------------|
|     5        |    1       |
|     5        |    2       |
|     5        |    3       |
|     12       |    1       |
|     12       |    2       |
|     12       |    3       |
|     12       |    4       |
```

How can I build my select statement to give me this results? I think there are two key tasks:

1) Select a row X times based on the amount

2) Set the position for each physical article

Comment: Your question may have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607669/select-rows-repeated-for-certain-count) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423767/sql-repeat-a-result-row-multiple-times-and-number-the-rows)

Comment: Thank you! The first question doesn't number the rows, but maybe it's possible to do this in a second step.. The second looks good! Maybe there is a way (a table-valued function) to generate these number tables on the fly...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this

```sql
SELECT ArticleID, n.n Position
  FROM table1 t JOIN
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
) n
    ON n.n <= t.amount
 ORDER BY ArticleID, Position
```

**Note:** subquery `n` generates a sequence of numbers on the fly from 1 to 100. If you do a lot of such queries you may consider to create persisted tally(numbers) table and use it instead.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fd25/2)** demo

or using a recursive CTE

```sql
WITH tally AS (
  SELECT 1 n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM tally WHERE n < 100
)
SELECT ArticleID, n.n Position
  FROM table1 t JOIN tally n
    ON n.n <= t.amount
 ORDER BY ArticleID, Position
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fd25/3)** demo

Output in both cases:

```
| ARTICLEID | POSITION |
|-----------|----------|
|         5 |        1 |
|         5 |        2 |
|         5 |        3 |
|        12 |        1 |
|        12 |        2 |
|        12 |        3 |
|        12 |        4 |
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe there is a way to generate a number table on the fly via a table valued function. I'll check this and report the status!

Comment: @Andy MySQL doesn't support table valued functions

Comment: Oh, I tagged it mysql accidentally. I'm working on a mssql server!

Comment: @Andy It will work in SQL Server too. See updated answer for another solution using a recursive CTE.

Comment: @Andy Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ca38/1)**

```
SELECT t1.[Article ID],
       t2.number 
FROM Table1 t1,
     master..spt_values t2
WHERE t1.Amount >= t2.number 
AND t2.type = 'P'
AND t2.number <= 255
AND t2.number <> 0
```

Result:

```
| ARTICLE ID | NUMBER |
|------------|--------|
|          5 |      1 |
|          5 |      2 |
|          5 |      3 |
|         12 |      1 |
|         12 |      2 |
|         12 |      3 |
|         12 |      4 |
```