# MySQL Query To Produce Amount Per Month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains:

```
id           date                   user_id   duration  amount
1            2014-01-01 00:00:00    1         1         £10
2            2014-01-02 00:00:00    2         2         £10
3            2014-01-03 00:00:00    3         3         £10
```

I'm trying to display the amount per month. Any ideas how to do this in a query?

Comment: [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and [date/time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions.

Comment: is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year) and in particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7721169/179125), which points to MySQL's very useful [`EXTRACT(unit FROM data)` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract).

Comment: @user3420034 Please give us an example table and result set in which the output corresponds to the input. Your random example doesn't give us enough information to write a query.

Comment: If there's a payment in 2014-01 with a duration of 2 months, does that mean £10 in 2014-01 and £10 in 2014-02, or does it mean £20 in 2014-01 only?

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumptions that you can extract the month from you datetime easily, so the real question is about the aggregation logic, and that you can create a numbers table.

Here is a simple example that shows the pattern.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d88a97/2)

```
CREATE TABLE Num (num int);
INSERT INTO Num VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4);

CREATE TABLE Tbl (start int, run int);
INSERT INTO Tbl VALUES (1,2),(2,3);

SELECT start + num active_month
      ,count(*) * 10 income
  FROM Tbl
       INNER JOIN
       Num ON num < run
GROUP BY start + num
```

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
SELECT a.my_date, a.income, IFNULL(SUM(DISTINCT(a.income)) + sum( b.income ), a.income) as roll_up
FROM (
SELECT purchase_id, DATE_FORMAT( date_purchased, '%y-%m') AS my_date, SUM( amount_income / duration ) AS "income"
FROM incomes
GROUP BY my_date
) AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT purchase_id, DATE_FORMAT( date_purchased, '%y-%m') AS my_date, SUM(amount_income / duration ) AS "income"
FROM incomes
GROUP BY my_date
) AS b ON ( a.purchase_id > b.purchase_id )
```

GROUP BY a.purchase_id

It's a bit tricky to do that in one shot - and it might be improved - but that gives the following results :

```
my_date  income     roll_up
13-12    8.5000     8.5000
14-01   10.0000     18.5000
14-02   16.6667     35.1667
```

My data set is :

```
1   2013-12-28 00:00:00     1   2   15
2   2014-01-04 00:00:00     2   1   10
3   2014-02-04 00:00:00     3   6   40
4   2013-12-29 00:00:00     4   1   1
5   2014-02-28 00:00:00     5   2   20
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Karl, I'm pretty sure some kind of numbers table is necessary here. Personally I like [the approach given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432083/179125), which defines a view (well, several of them) to generate numbers, instead of having to actually store a table full of numbers. Whether you use a table or a view, when you `SELECT` from it, it just looks like this:

```
 n
---
 0
 1
 2
 3
 …
```

With that you can construct a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
  purchases.purchase_id,
  purchases.date_purchased,
  purchases.duration,
  -- generator_16 is our numbers table
  generator_16.n,
  -- Below we calculate the year and month (year_mon) in the following way:
  -- (1) Get the first day of the year, e.g. if date_purchased is 2012-12-28,
  --     this gives us 2012-01-01.
  -- (2) Get the month number, e.g. 12 for 2012-12-28) and add that many months
  --     to the first day of the year, which gives us the first day of the
  --     month, 2012-12-01.
  -- (3) Add "n" months, where "n" is the number we get from the numbers table,
  --     starting at 0.
  DATE_ADD(                                              -- (3)
    DATE_ADD(                                            -- (2)
      MAKEDATE( YEAR(purchases.date_purchased), 1 ),     -- (1)
      INTERVAL MONTH(purchases.date_purchased) - 1 MONTH -- (2)
    ),
    INTERVAL generator_16.n MONTH                        -- (3)
  ) AS year_mon,
  purchases.amount_income / purchases.duration AS amount
FROM purchases
-- The below JOIN means that if `purchases.duration` is 3, we get three rows
-- that have 0, 1, and 2 in the `n` column, which we use as the number of dates
-- to add in (3) above.
JOIN generator_16
ON generator_16.n BETWEEN 0 AND purchases.duration - 1
ORDER BY purchases.purchase_id, year_mon;
```

This gives us a result like this ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88aad/2)):

```
purchase_id  date_purchased  duration  n      year_mon  amount
-----------  --------------  --------  -  ------------  ------
          1    2013-12-28 …         2  0  2013-12-01 …     7.5
          1    2013-12-28 …         2  1  2014-01-01 …     7.5

          2    2014-01-04 …         1  0  2014-01-01 …      10

          3    2014-02-04 …         6  0  2014-02-01 …  6.6667
          3    2014-02-04 …         6  1  2014-03-01 …  6.6667
          3    2014-02-04 …         6  2  2014-04-01 …  6.6667
          3    2014-02-04 …         6  3  2014-05-01 …  6.6667
          3    2014-02-04 …         6  4  2014-06-01 …  6.6667
          3    2014-02-04 …         6  5  2014-07-01 …  6.6667
```

I inserted blank lines to separate the `purchase_id` groups so you can see how `n` increases from `0` to `duration - 1` with each item in the group. As you can see, `year_mon` is equal to `n` months after the first day of the `date_purchased` month plus `n` months, and `amount` is equal to `amount_income / duration`.

We're almost done, but as you can see `year_mon` has repetition: `2014-01-01` is shown twice. This is great news, because we can then use `GROUP BY` to group by that column and `SUM(amount)` to get the total for that month:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE_ADD(
    DATE_ADD(
      MAKEDATE( YEAR(purchases.date_purchased), 1 ),
      INTERVAL MONTH(purchases.date_purchased) - 1 MONTH
    ),
    INTERVAL generator_16.n MONTH
  ) AS year_mon,
  SUM(purchases.amount_income / purchases.duration) AS total
FROM purchases
JOIN generator_16
ON generator_16.n BETWEEN 0 AND purchases.duration - 1
GROUP BY year_mon
ORDER BY year_mon;
```

The only difference between this query and the previous month is that we do `GROUP BY year_mon` and then `SUM(amount_income / duration)` to get `total` for the month, yielding this result ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88aad/3)):

```
    year_mon   total
------------  ------
2013-12-01 …     7.5
2014-01-01 …    17.5
2014-02-01 …  6.6667
2014-03-01 …  6.6667
2014-04-01 …  6.6667
2014-05-01 …  6.6667
2014-06-01 …  6.6667
2014-07-01 …  6.6667
```

...and of course you can use `DATE_FORMAT` and `CAST` or `ROUND` to get nicely-formatted dates and amounts, or you can do that in your front-end code.