# Separating the list of value by comparing frequency

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the bellow data set output should come like less then one frequency..
i am new to sql so don't have much idea..

in the input i have 3 times 1, 2 times 2, 3 times 3 and 2 times 4. output i want 2 times 1, 1 time 2, 2 times 3 and 1 time 4..

Any suggestion how to achieve this output!!

[image]

Comment: what you've tried so far?

Comment: Are you sure output can contain duplicate values? If yes - what is the rule?

Comment: in the input i have 3 times 1, 2 times 2, 3 times 3 and 2 times 4. output i want 2 times 1, 1 time 2, 2 times 3 and 1 time 4..

Comment: So, one time less for each? if there is ID=5 in input should it be reflected in output at all?

Comment: yes if it is present single time.. it should not display in output..

Comment: Looks like you are searching the maximum number of consecutive values  (or longest sequence) for each value. i.e. if you had `1,2,3,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4` the output would be `1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be written in a more compact form, but just for clarity:

```
With Src As (        --< Source table
    Select * From (Values (1),(2),(3),(1),(1),(2),(3),(3),(4),(4),(5)) V (Id)
), Numbers As (      --< Auxiliary table with numbers from 1 to maximum row count of Src
    Select ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By Id) As N From Src
), Counted As (      --< Calculate current number of ID occurances
    Select Id, Count(Id) As Cnt From Src Group By Id
)
    Select Id
    From Counted                 --< From distinct list of IDs
    Inner Join Numbers           --< replicate each row
    On Numbers.N < Counted.Cnt   --< one less time than the Cnt
```

Expression to replicate the row taken from [SQL: Repeat a result row multiple times...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10423798/5690722)

[jpw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175077/jpw) implementation *(please feel free to copy it into your own answer)*:

```
With Src As (                                --< Source table
    Select * From (Values (1),(2),(3),(1),(1),(2),(3),(3),(4),(4),(5)) V (Id)
), Numbered As (                             --< Number ID occurances
    Select Id, row_number() Over (Partition By id Order By id) As n From Src
)
    Select Id From Numbered Where n > 1      --< Take one off
```

Comment: Updated following clarification in comments to the question

Comment: You could partition the data in the row_number function and filter out rows with number 1. It should be more efficient: Something like `numbers as (      
    select id, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as n from src
) select id from numbers where n <> 1` It renders a better looking execution plan in my test.