# Expand the rows into multiple rows based on the count column in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

Suppose I have a table as below,

```
ID         word            count
1           A                 3
1           B                 2
1           C                 4
2           D                 2
2           E                 3
```

I want to expand the table into multiple rows based on the count column. If the count has 3 as value, then I want to create 3 rows. Similarly I want to do it for all of them. The output should be as follows,

```
ID         word            count
1           A                 3
1           A                 3
1           A                 3
1           B                 2
1           B                 2
1           C                 4
1           C                 4
1           C                 4
1           C                 4
2           D                 2
2           D                 2
2           E                 3
2           E                 3
2           E                 3
```

Can anybody help me in doing this is SQL?

Comment: tag only one database being used.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik I am using an Hadoop. Running Hive queries on top of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used http://sqlfiddle.com to test this out. There must be a better way than having a table with numbers. I took the idea from a link that I forgot (sorry). Hope this gives you an idea to find a better solution.

EDIT: Here's the link where I got the idea from: [SQL: Repeat a result row multiple times, and number the rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423767/sql-repeat-a-result-row-multiple-times-and-number-the-rows)

[image]

[image]